# How to redesign a Slider Indicator?

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I have a carousel and I want achieve the design as in the picture:
Design I want to achieve

[image]

The indicators are rendered as text with a bar that indicates active slide. How do I achieve this design?

Tried with css and javascipt but not getting what I want. Please help I am new to web development.

Comment: add your code also, so we find where is issue

Comment: You can use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/ which allows any level of customization in the indicators and can enter the text as per your need.